# Process.Start() results in error messages: Parameter cannot be null

Tags: c#, process, mstest

Starting a process object results in UI message boxes being displayed with the message:

*

> Parameter cannot be null. Parameter name: Source

*

As a result, my code execution gets suspended even though my app does not observe any exceptions.

I thought that the file path to the files may have been too long.
So I provided a shorter path and copied all the files to that directory. However, I still have the same issue.

The issue occurs as soon as I execute **"process.Start()"**.

**Code:**

```
private void RunTests(ref int passingTests, ref int totalTests, ref int failedTests)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(TEST_DLL_PATH);
    var copiedFile = Path.Combine(TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH, fileName);

    //Now Create all of the directories
    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(TEST_DLL_DIRECTORY_PATH, "*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(TEST_DLL_DIRECTORY_PATH, TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH));

    //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(TEST_DLL_DIRECTORY_PATH, "*.*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(TEST_DLL_DIRECTORY_PATH, TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH), true);

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe",
            Arguments = string.Format(@"/testcontainer:""{0}"" /resultsfile:""{1}""", copiedFile, TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

        if (line.Contains("test(s) Passed") || _count % 5 == 0)
        {
            var parts = line.Split('/');
            passingTests = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            totalTests = int.Parse(parts[1].Split(' ')[0]);
            failedTests = totalTests - passingTests;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a DLL that was being executed via a unit test that my process was running was throwing up a GUI dialog on an exception.

I ended up creating a unit-testable interaction interface to handle error messages based on UI versus Test Automation.